# Php loop throught Xml nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I have Xml file like

```
<response>
<tag1>
    <item>
        <id>106</id>
        <title>DG</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>105</id>
        <title>AC</title>
    </item>
</tag1>
<tag2>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>DjG</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>15</id>
        <title>AoC</title>
    </item>
</tag2>
</response>
```

I trying this code to extract ID and Title

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->load('xml.xml');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    foreach($xpath->evaluate('//response/*') as $node){
    $params =$xpath->evaluate('//response/' .$node->nodeName . '/item/*');
        foreach($params as $child) {
            echo $node->nodeName ." = " .$child->nodeName ." = " .$child->nodeValue ."\n<br>";
        }
    }
```

But I get result such

```
<br>tag1 = id = 106
<br>tag1 = title = DG
<br>tag1 = id = 105
<br>tag1 = title = AC
<br>tag2 = id = 1
<br>tag2 = title = DjG
<br>tag2 = id = 15
<br>tag2 = title = AoC
```

But i need to get like this

> tag1 = 106 = DG
>       
> tag1 = 105 = AC
>       
> tag2 = 1 = DjG
>       
> tag2 = 15 = AoC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the second `foreach`, just target that `$node->nodeName`, then on the inner foreach target each id an title.

```
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//response/*') as $node) {
    $tag = $node->nodeName;
    $params = $xpath->evaluate("//$tag/*");
    foreach($params as $child) {
        $id = $xpath->evaluate('string(./id)', $child);
        $title = $xpath->evaluate('string(./title)', $child);
        echo $tag ." = " .$id ." = " .$title ."\n<br>";
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/X2JZH6)

Or the `SimpleXML` version:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');
foreach($xml as $tag =>$node) {
    foreach($node as $item => $child) {
        echo $tag ." = " .$child->id ." = " .$child->title ."\n<br>";
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ohBHT9)

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin just get the individual child, check my revision

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin i can't be sure which, maybe benchmark would yield accurate results, `SimpleXML`'s lines are shorter thats for sure.

Comment: second variant is usable if "response" tag is root, but if not when how to use? `foreach($xml->response` ?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin yes could be, if `<response>` is a direct child of the root node.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load('xml.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//response/*') as $node){
    $params =$xpath->evaluate('//response/' .$node->nodeName . '/*');

     foreach($params as $child) 
    {
       echo $node->nodeName ." = " .$child->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->textContent ." = " .$child->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent  ."\n<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$item

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of DOMXpath::evaluate() is the context node. If you do not start the XPath expression with a slash, it will be relative to it. So inside a loop, you usually want to use the current node as the context for your expressions.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/absolute-expression') as $node) {
  var_dump(
     $xpath->evaluate('relative-expression', $node)
  );
}
```

XPath (unlike CSS selectors) can fetch properties of the elements along different axes. You can get the local name (without namespace prefix) of a parent node with:

`local-name(parent::*)`

Using this, you can solve the problem with a single loop iterating the `item` elements.

Example:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//response/*/item') as $node) {
  echo 
    $xpath->evaluate('local-name(parent::*)', $node), ' = ',
    $xpath->evaluate('string(id)', $node), ' = ',
    $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $node), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
tag1 = 106 = DG
tag1 = 105 = AC
tag2 = 1 = DjG
tag2 = 15 = AoC
```

Only, If you need to call source for each first level node (tag1, tag2). You will need two loops. Like output the items grouped by the tag* element node.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//response/*') as $node) {
  echo  
    $xpath->evaluate('local-name()', $node), 
    "\n--------\n";
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('item', $node) as $item) {
    echo 
      $xpath->evaluate('string(id)', $item), ' = ',
      $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $item), "\n";
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
tag1
--------
106 = DG
105 = AC

tag2
--------
1 = DjG
15 = AoC
```

Comment: only trouble how to use put each local-name to separate php file as array `$data= "\n'" .$xpath->evaluate('string(id)', $node) ."' => '" .$xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $node). "',";`  _ `file_put_contents("." .$path .$xpath->evaluate('local-name(parent::*)', $node) .'.php', '<?php $arr = array(' .$data .'\n);\n?>' );` not work wery well

Comment: This is not an request in your original question.  I added an example to my answer.